# how to Install Application programmatically on android N

Tags: android, apk, android-install-apk

I am Following these steps
but for sdk version N ,android system showing a alert dialog box "Package installer has stopped" while installing the app.

: 1 - Add the following to the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<provider
    android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/paths"/>
</provider>
```

2 - Add the following paths.xml file to the xml folder(if not exist create it) on res in src, main

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <external-path
 name="external_file"
 path="."/>
</paths>
```

The pathName is that shown in the exemplary content uri example above and pathValue is the actual path on the system. It would be a good idea to put a "." for pathValue in the above if you do not want to add any extra subdirectory.

3 - Write the following code to Run Your Apk files:

```
File file = "path of yor apk file";
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
 Uri fileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getBaseContext(), 
 getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", file);
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, fileUri);
 intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_NOT_UNKNOWN_SOURCE, true) ;
 intent.setDataAndType(fileUri, "application/vnd.android" + ".package-
 archive");
 intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | 
 Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
 intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
 startActivity(intent);

} else {
   Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

  intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file),"application/vnd.android.package-
  archive");
  intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
  startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: As i know u cannot install a application programatically from another application , at the max u can download the file , i also tried same before some days, it requires users permission to install the app.

Comment: it is working perfectly for every version except android N

Answer (score 1):

First, set the target SDK Version to 26 (Android Oreo) to make everything to work.

Then follow these steps below:

> 1. How to check if the installation is allowed?

You can check everywhere using `getPackageManager().canRequestPackageInstalls()` in your activity. Note that this boolean rerurns always `false` if you dont declare that permission or selecting the wrong SDK Version.

> 2. What permission i need to request?

You need to declare `Mainfest.permission.REQUEST_PACKAGE_INSTALLS` into your app manifest, so here is it:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_PACKAGE_INSTALLS" />
```

> 3. How can i prompt user to grant permission?

Here you can do something like this:

```
startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_UNKNOWN_APP_SOURCES, Uri.parse("package:".concat("your.package.name"))));
```

> 4. How to prompt user to install apk?

Once you have completed all other steps, you can prompt the user to install package using this code:

```
Intent installIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE);
installIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_RETURN_RESULT, true); //this is necessary if you want to know if the installation was success, failed or cancelled.
installIntent.setData(Uri.fromFile(new File("/sdcard/yourapk.apk"))); //replace yourapk to your apk name
startActivityForResult(installIntent, 1);
```

You may need also to add `installIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_RETURN_RESULT, true);` if you want to know if the installation was success, failed or cancelled.